# Форма, проверка на value, почему не работает код?

Tags: javascript, html

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form__item');
    const formBtn = document.querySelector('.form__btn');
    const formBtnClose = document.querySelector('.form__btn-close');

    const check = () => {
      if(inputs[0].value != '' || inputs[1].value != '' || inputs[2].value != ''){
        formBtn.disabled = false;
        formBtnClose.disabled = false;
      }else{
        formBtn.disabled = true;
        formBtnClose.disabled = true;
      }
    };
    inputs[0].addEventListener('keyup', check);
    inputs[1].addEventListener('keyup', check);
    inputs[2].addEventListener('keyup', check);
```

когда я пишу - кнопка становиться активной, но когда я стираю и значение пустое - кнопка не превращается обратно в disabled, помогите пожалуйста!

```
<form class="form__main" action="#" method="POST">
                            <div class="form__inputs">
                                <div class="form__item form__item_email">
                                <input class="form__input" type="email" name="userEmail" placeholder="Email...">
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form__item form__item_tel">
                            <input  class="form__input " type="tel" name="userPhone" placeholder="Phone...">
                            <span></span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form__item form__item_message">
                                <textarea name="message" class="form__textarea form__input" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                                 
                            <div class="form__buttons">
                                <button class="form__btn" type="submit" disabled>submit</button>
                           <button class="form__btn-close" type="reset" disabled><img src="./img/icons/close.svg" alt="reset"></button> 
                           <!-- <div class="moon"></div> -->
                            </div>
                          
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выбираете не те элементы.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form__input');
                                                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: Когда первый раз пишу - все ok, но когда начинаю стирать - не становиться disabled

Comment: @Nikita - добавьте html  в вопрос.

Comment: html добавил в задачу

Comment: Может нужно на foreach переписать?

Comment: Спасибо!! Я тут новый:) и еще много не знаю, как тебя отблагодарить?

Comment: @Nikita Пожалуйста. Все нормально. Успехов!

Comment: И тебе:) а как ты так быстро ответил? Я думал тут очень много вопросов и мой будет неинтересен или просто не будет ответа